# How to get the Distance between ChildWindow and Parent Window?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Can we calculate the gap bettwen ChildWindow and ParentWidnow?

While I can Drag arround the ChildWindow there is a Distance from the Top and Left.

WHile I try to get the Distance using:

```
ChildWindow.Margin
```

it is returning 0,0,0,0

Is there any other method to get the Distance bettwen ChildWindow and ParantWindow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A child window control actually occupies all the available space on the Silverlight content window.  The first element in the template is the overlay `Grid`.  Its this Grid which dims the "parent" window content and consumes all the mouse events that would otherwise go to "parent" content.

Inside the Overlay `Grid` is another Grid called "ContentRoot" which contains the border, chrome and your child content.  Its this `Grid` that gets dragged around and will have a Margin.

Using this extension method:-

```
public static class VisualTreeEnumeration  
{  
   public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)  
   {  
     int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);  
     for (int i=0; i < count; i++)  
     {  
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);  
       yield return child;  
       foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child))  
         yield return descendent;  
     }  
   }  
}
```

You could find the ContentRoot with:-

```
Grid contentRoot = myChildWindow.Descendents().OfType<Grid>().Where(g => g.Name == "ContentRoot");
```

From which you get the margin

Comment: Thanks Anthony but I am Unable to get  the Method Descendents() for my ChildWindow myChildWindow

Comment: @Subhen: You have included the above class in your project and you understand how `extension` methods work?

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with PointToScreen and PointFromScreen methods of your windows.

[PointFromScreen article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointfromscreen.aspx)

[PointToScreen article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.pointtoscreen.aspx)

Comment: Unable to get PointFromScreen and PointToScreen Method for ChildWindow. I am currently using SL.